# Make randomly given attributes like img,srcs unique in a gallery grid

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this script for grid gallery that changes images randomly one at the time every 3s, by changing its srcset attribute, there's always 15 visible images but array is made out of 28 and since its random sometimes happens that there are 3 or more of the same image, there's chance to have all 15 be the same (crazy small chance but you get my point) and i want to prevent it somehow.

I was thinking about somehow defining that there's always 2 same attributes possible at most, so it wont change other img to that attribute if there are 2 of those. Or if its possible, this would be perfect, to have only one of attribute visible and it wont add that to other img if there is exactly that attribute.

Im ok with having at most 2 of the same attributes since it will minimize chance of seeing them both at the same time since half is hidden and it will prevent seeig 3 or more.

Heres the jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    //array
    var dice = $('.attachment-lenslight_squares').map(function() {
        return $(this).attr('srcset')
    }).get();

    $('.attachment-lenslight_squares')
        .click(function() {
            var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * dice.length);
            $(this).fadeOut(200, function() {
                $(this).attr('srcset', dice[num]);
            }).fadeIn(200);
        });

    setInterval(function() {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
        $('.attachment-lenslight_squares').eq(rand).click();
    }, 3000);

});
```

Thanks for ideas

Comment: Put your 28 possible values in an array, sort it in random order, take the first 15 items.

Comment: @pawel this wont work, since all of 28 are uniqe, what i need is that added attribute is not duplicate (or 2 existing at most), since there is one added from array every 3 seconds, ah im bad at explaining it

Comment: But you already have them in the `dice` array. Just randomize the array, then use an incrementing index instead of random * length for `num`. Once you reach the end start from 0.

Comment: @pawel can you help me with specific code to do that? sadly im not really good with jquery, this one took me like 4 hours to at least get it working. Sorry to bother you and thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a counter for every image (with an object) and decide if the counter is below a certain value, like `3` and if not, then get another random value.

For deleted (or hidden) images, decrement the counter.

Answer (score 0):

> there's always 15 visible images but array is made out of 28

**Grid Initialisation:**

1. Set up the original array of 28 images
2. Copy the array and call the copy `presentImages`
3. Select 13 images randomly from `presentImages`, remove them and build a 13 image array called `absentImages`
4. You now have *3 arrays* - the original (which you won't be using), `presentImages` and `absentImages`
5. Populate the grid gallery with images from `presentImages`

**When it's time to change an image:**

1. Remove the image from the grid and replace it with `absentImages[0]`
2. Move `absentImages[0]` from `absentImages` array to `presentImages` array
3. Move the image most recently removed from the grid from `presentImages` to `absentImages` so that it becomes the new last image in the `absentImages` array

Answer (score 0):

Below is sample code to get unique and random 15 items from existing images array:

```
var mainImages = [], random; // 28 or more items
//at first :  max = 15, count = 0 , indexes = [] 
getUniqueRandomIndexs(max, count, indexs){
    // return images after generating unique items
    if(indexs.length == max) return indexes;
    // dont use which is already used : mainImages.length-count 
    random = math.random(0,mainImages.length-1-count);
    indexs.push(mainImages[random]);
    count++;
    // swap pushed image to last of the mainImages array, so that next time wont be using it.
    mainImages[random] = mainImages[mainImages.length-1-count];
    mainImages[mainImages.length-1-count]; = indexs[indexs.length-1];
    retunr getUniqueRandomIndexs(max, count, indexs);
}
```

Each 3 second this function will return the unique images array.

> It is seems to be same as picking **`unique & random`** movie cd from a stack of cd, and after watching keep it at the **`last of stack`** so that we can easily skip next time while picking up a new random unique movie cd.